# sqlserverv8.node is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: angular, npm

While I deploy my node.js app on stage, I am getting the following error from server side.

```js
Error: \\?\C:\[MyApp]\Server\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\build\Release\sqlserverv8.node is not a valid Win32 application.
\\?\C:\[MyApp]\Server\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\build\Release\sqlserverv8.node
    at Module._extensions..node (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1302:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at C:\[MyApp]\Server\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\util.js:5:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\[MyApp]\Server\node_modules\msnodesqlv8\lib\util.js:35:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32) {
  code: 'ERR_DLOPEN_FAILED'
}
```

I thought this issue could be related to the version of msnodesqlv8 package, so I did upgrade it to 4.1.0, which is the latest with no luck..

Any ideas please? FYI, this is the angular version:

```js
Angular CLI: 12.0.0
Node: 18.13.0
Package Manager: npm 7.13.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1200.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         12.0.0 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   12.0.0 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          12.0.0 (cli-only)
```

I am unsure if I should upgrade angular version. Please advise.